# How do you specify command line arguments in a .csproj's StartProgram setting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm trying to specify command line arguments to an executable in a `<StartProgram>` value of a `<PropertyGroup>`  Currently looks like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
  <StartProgram>$(SolutionDir)\Edge.Express\node.exe</StartProgram>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm trying to automate the steps involved in attaching my library to a running process so my team can directly debug a library without additional ceremony (They're not familiar with Visual Studio yet)

I copied the node executable to the Edge.Express folder and my Express server configuration is in server.js at that location.  What I *want* to do is this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
  <StartProgram>$(SolutionDir)\Edge.Express\node.exe server</StartProgram>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but that throws the following exception
[image: Exception]

Removing the "server" arg fires up an instance of node.

How would I give the "server" argument to node.exe inside my `<StartProgram>` setting?

**Alternatively**
Is there a way to set the StartAction to run a batch script and just push the server startup into the script?

A quick search did not return any documentation on what the available StartActions are

Comment: Use StartArguments to specify arguments.

Comment: That did the trick; now new error "The program 'node.exe' has exited with code 8 (0x8)" but StartArguments was the key

Comment: So, I got this up and running. The point of this was to allow my team to directly debug library files without having to spin up a server manually (pointed to the correct config) and then Debug |Attach the library project to the running process.  I had to deal with the code 8 crash, but it was due to a relative reference being improperly defined for my new server location.  PSR helped me track the error (the console window crashed and closed instantaneously) and I now have the endpoints of an ExpressJS WebApi consuming a CLR library and that library is debuggable in 2013 Web Express; beautiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Hans pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492099/how-do-you-specify-command-line-arguments-in-a-csprojs-startprogram-setting#comments-26492099): If you want to specify arguments for the `<StartAction>` *Program*, you have to use the `<StartArguments>` element:

```xml
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>$(SolutionDir)\Edge.Express\node.exe</StartProgram>
<StartArguments>server</StartArguments>
```

Comment: Is there a way for `<StartArguments>` to work when you have "Start project" selected in Project Properties instead of "Start program"?

Comment: @Dai yes, this combination is working. just set the Application startup object to be a valid main method accepting arguments.